# Middleman object for access management?

Tags: c++

I have two classes:

```
class World {
 public:
       void update();
       void addObject(GameObject* obj);
       std::vector<GameObject const*> getGameObjectsAt(float x,float y,float radius) const;
 private:
       std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects
}

class GameObject {
 public:
   void update();
}
```

Now I want `GameObject` to be able to call `getGameObjectsAt` and `addObject` from `World` in its `update` function. However I don't want `GameObject` to be able to call the `update` function of `World`.

---

I could make a new class `WorldSomething` that contains my `World` object and has the functions `addObject` and `getGameObjectsAt`. I could then pass my `WorldSomething` object to the `GameObject` update function:

```
class World {
   public:
       void update();
   private:
       std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects
}



 class WorldSomething {
     public:
        void addObject(GameObject* obj);
        std::vector<GameObject const*> getGameObjectsAt(float x,float y,float     radius) const;
     private:
        World* world;
 }

class GameObject {
  public:
   void update(const WorldSomething& worldSomething);
}
```

However this moves my operations further away from my data, and I have to pass my WorldSomething object to the update function of GameObject. Is there a better solution? (I'm using c++ if that helps...) Also what would you call such a `WorldSomething` class?

Comment: Make the "private" members `private`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: update() of World needs to be public, since it is called from another part of my code. (my game loop)

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why it's an issue if GameObject could call the update function of World? Also, if the only object that should be allowed to call `update` is the game loop, then you may want to think about a friend relationship. Alternatively, a visitor pattern, where update is called if the visitor is the gameloop, and something else otherwise.

Comment: Why would `GameObject` call `World`'s functions.It doesn't make sense for a `gameObject` to get a list of all `gameObject`s using itself(through object).Instead i think `gameObject` should work independently because that's why you have created it as a separate class.If you want to have a list of all other `gameObject`s, that manipulation should be done and used in `World` class itself.

Comment: The update() of World isn't public in your code. How is another part of your code calling it?

Comment: @blackpen Agreed, the OP probably oversimplified their example code.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Each gameObject is responsible for how it behaves (moves etc...). And how it behaves is strongly dependent on other gameObjects. I thought it would be a good idea to have the code thats responsible for how the gameObject behaves actually inside that gameObject.

Comment: @macco If each `gameObject` depends on other `gameObject`s then all should be part of the same class, which is why it would be a good idea to have that code in `World`

Comment: @GauravSehgal I don't think I understand. Can you elaborate? Maybe I forgot to say that GameObject is only the base class. It gets specialized into many various different objects and each has different behavior.

Comment: @mocco You can very well achieve what you are trying using another class(or may be something else) but it would be better if you spend some time in rethinking the design.A class should be responsible for its own resources.If gameObject is a class, it should be responsible for that gameObject and not other gameObjects.A `world` class would have all `gameObject`s and this `world` class should be responsible how the underlying `gameObject`s interact.Consider this, `class A` has resource `B[20]`.Now `class B` is trying to all other `B`s which are in `A` .This is probably not the best design.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Thanks. I get what you are saying. However a gameObject would and should never modify another gameObject. It only has to get information about other gameObjects like their position and velocity etc. But the same can be said for behavioral responsibility? A gameObject should be responsible for its own behaviour. Making another class responsible for its behavior would break that. So is it a tradeoff between responsibility for its own resources and its own behaviour, or can I have both?

Comment: @macco, each GameObject should be responsible for magnaging its own information or behaviour. It should expose just enough information to the World so that the World can figure out how something, like a collision, could take place between two GameObjects. It isn't perfect, but probably enough for a simple case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However this moves my operations further away from my data ...

That's actually desired.

---

Use interfaces in 1st place to decouple logic and data:

```
struct IWorldAdd {
    virtual void addObject(GameObject* obj) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<GameObject const*> getGameObjectsAt(float x,float y,float radius) 
        const = 0;
    virtual ~IWorldAdd() {};
};
```

---

```
class World : public IWorldAdd{
 public:
    void update();
    void addObject(GameObject* obj);
    std::vector<IGameObject const*> getGameObjectsAt(float x,float y,float radius) const;
 private:
       std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects
};
```

---

```
struct IGameObject {
     virtual void update() = 0;
     virtual Point getCenterPosition() = 0;
     virtual ~IGameObject() {}
};
```

---

Add a strategy that provides the logic

```
template<class UpdateStrategy>
class GameObject : public IGameObject {
 public:
   GameObject(UpdateStrategy* strategy) : strategy_(strategy)
   void update() {
       // Do stuff needed to update the things directly related to the 
       // GameObject's rendering and such

       // Call the strategy needed to update a particular game object
       // in Relation to other objects nearby
       strategy_->updateRestOfWorld();
   }
private:
   UpdateStrategy* strategy_;
};
```

---

```
class AConcreteUpdateStrategy {
    AConcreteUpdateStrategy(IWorldAdd* world) : world_(world) {
    }

    void updateRestOfWorld(const IGameObject* gameObject) {
         Point centerPoint gameObject->getCenterPosition();
         std::vector<const IGameObject*> otherGameObjects = 
             world_->getGameObjectsAt(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.x, 500 );
         // Inspect if there are specific game objects nearby
         if(gameObjectIsNearBy) {
              world->addObject(new OtherGameObject());
         }
    }
private:
    IWorldAdd* world_;
};
```

This is a rough sketch, hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. I think that making a IWorld interface is a pretty good solution. Having Strategy classes adds a bit too much complexity for what I'm trying to do, but I might add them later if they prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your **World** class is responsible for **two** different aspects. You see, when you are thinking that some part of your code should only be using "half" of your **World** class; then maybe your **World** is too big?

In other words: would it be reasonable to come up with a class **HalfOfTheWorld** that contains those functions that your Game objects needs?!

And then you might have **AnotherHalfOftheWorld** delivering the other aspects; and if needed; your **World** class can then contain one member of each of those new classes.

Comment: Isn't that something like a _Strategy Pattern_ that should be applied to `World`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better solution?

I think it's best to leave the classes as is.

I don't see any advantage to adding another layer (or more layers) just to prevent `GameObject` from being able to call `World::update()`.

Programmer discipline is the solution. Make sure that your flow of execution is well understood by your developers. `World::update()` wouldn't be called from `GameObject` if the flow of execution does not require it.